# QGIS 3.16.4: invisible shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have to add a shapefile created by another person in my project, she shares it by Google Drive.
In the folder there are five files: .cph, .cbf, .prj, .shp and .shx. I add it and the layer correctly shows up in the left browser panel but it doesn't show in the project.
I checked the reference and the settings and properties.
After I didn't manage the problem my coworker sent the files again, but the results were the same.

In the past days, we used the same strategy to share the work with no problems, I add other files without issues, it's only this one that resists.

Comment: I guess that .cbf is actually `.dbf`, right?

Comment: Do you see rows in the attribute table? Try the vector tools "Repair shapefile" and "Fix geometries".

Comment: What happens when you zoom to the layer? Which CRS is the layer in? Which CRS should it be in? Did someone save the shapefile using a not-fitting CRS?

Comment: yes, it's .dbf. Im'm sorry. The attribute table it's empty. The CRS is EPSG:3003, like all the other layers

Comment: Thank you BERA, I try with "fix" but the algorith can't find errors

Comment: It's possible your colleague has sent the wrong file or doesn't actually have the data. Ask her to check the file size of the individual files before sending them through. If the .dbf is 1KB then it's empty anyway and the problem is on her end

Comment: Thank you, I'll ask her again. At this point I simply don't know what else to check